# Akka payload exception catch

Tags: exception, timeout, akka, payload

I need to catch the payload exceeded exception thrown by akka. This is because in case my payload is more than the permissible amount set in config file, the response just ends with a timeout.
Instead of this present scenario, I would like to catch the exception akka throws in case payload is exceeded instead of waiting for a timeout. Can anyone help how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to catch the payload exceeded exception thrown by akka.

You can't.

[`OversizedPayloadException`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.5.4/akka-remote/src/main/scala/akka/remote/Endpoint.scala#L173) is internal to the Akka remoting capability and is on a thread that is invisible to your code. There is no way for your application to capture that exception. (And it's not thrown, but logged, as seen [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.5.4/akka-remote/src/main/scala/akka/remote/Endpoint.scala#L790) and [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.5.4/akka-remote/src/main/scala/akka/remote/Endpoint.scala#L998), but that's a tangential fact.)

Having said that, one way to move forward is to follow the suggestions in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45440536/akka-payload-size-exceeded/45551094#45551094) to a related question that you asked.

Comment: Then, is it possible to know the size of the message being exchanged (encoded message size) so that I could handle that before itself before the message is exchanged between the actors?